# ingress get the 503 feedback

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to config the ingress to work with my domain name.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: app-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /my-api2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
  - name: app1
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 80
  - name: app2
    port: 4000
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-api
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: XXX
        ports:
        - name: app1
          containerPort: 3000
      - name: app2
        image: XXX
        ports:
        - name: app2
          containerPort: 4000
```

I can reach the app1 service by serverIP:3000(example. `172.16.111.211:3000/my-api1`). But remotely it always return the 503 status code(`curl https://example.com/my-api1`).

```
# kubectl describe ingress app-ingress
Name:             app-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          serverIP
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  app-tls terminates example.com
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  example.com
                      /my-api1(/|$)(.*)   app1:80 (<error: endpoints "app1" not found>)
                      /my-api2            app2:80 (<error: endpoints "app2" not found>)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. First thing is your service name is not matching, you have created a service with name my-api but in ingress you have referred it as app1 and app2 which is not available.
2. Second error is selector label between your deployment and service are not matching. Deployment created with label user-api but in service selector is mentioned as my-api.
3. If you need 80 port for both the application then you have to create two different services and refer that in your ingress.

Below should work for your requirement.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: app-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /my-api2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-api
  ports:
  - name: app1
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2
spec:
  selector:
    app: user-api
  ports:
  - name: app2
    port: 4000
    targetPort: 80
----

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: user-api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: user-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: user-api
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: XXX
        ports:
        - name: app1
          containerPort: 3000
      - name: app2
        image: XXX
        ports:
        - name: app2
          containerPort: 4000
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake on `port` and `targetPort`.
It should be:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-api
  ports:
  - name: app1
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  - name: app2
    port: 4000
    targetPort: 4000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: app-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /my-api1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: my-api
          servicePort: app1
      - path: /my-api2
        backend:
          serviceName: my-api
          servicePort: app2
```

- `port` is for exposing service port
- `targetPort` is targeting a pod exposed port

Comment: It report the duplicate port 80 error, it seems cannot be hold two 80 ports.

Comment: ohh. I didn't notice. Update my answer. And it also need to update ingress.

Comment: no, I mean the two 80 port is what I want, but it should have some extra config to let it work.

Comment: If you want two 80 port service, then you'll need two separated service yaml.

Comment: I'll suggest you to name the port with same service. (Updated answer)